# Closure call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

Have just found in https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js the following way to declare and call closure:

```
(function() {
...
}()); <-- this part
```

as I used to the following one:

```
(function() {
...
})(); <-- this part
```

and actually many other libraries use the 2nd form.

What is the difference between them, and in which context they will be different?

Comment: This is generally known as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). The difference of style isn't important.